# Isomorphism of Vector Spaces between Manifolds

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Hi i am reading "An introduction to Manifolds" by Loring Tu. And there in one proof at the last line it is written that "Hence, $F_*$ and $G_*$ are isomorphisms." But they've not proved that the mappings $F_*$ and $G_*$ are one-one,onto and linear transformation. I am able to understand all the steps done there except the very last step where they've written "hence $F_*$ and $G_*$ are isomorphisms". I am attaching the screenshot where the step is highligted . They've shown:$$(G\circ F)_*=\mathbb 1_{{T_p}N}$$ and $$(F\circ G)_*=\mathbb 1_{T_{F(p)}M}$$ My problem is that how does this prove that the mappings are isomorphisms.Also i am attaching another screenshot where the definition of the differential $F_*$ is given .[image: Screenshot 1]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An isomorphism of vector spaces is by definition a linear transformation which is invertible (and whose inverse is also linear... but this is automatically true). What does it mean for a function $f:A\to B$ to be invertible? By definition this means there must exist a $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g = \text{id}_B$ and $g\circ f=\text{id}_A$ (and of course, if such a $g$ exists, then it is unique).

What the proof shows is that the linear transformations $F_{*,p}:T_pN\to T_{F(p)}M$ and $G_{*,F(p)}:T_{F(p)}M\to T_pN$ are inverse functions hence they're isomorphisms of the appropriate tangent spaces.

Comment: this does make sense but the definition that i am familiar with is as follows: Let $U(F)$ and $V(F)$ be two vector spaces. Then a mapping $f:U\to V$ is called an isomorphism if f is one-one , f is onto and $f(a\alpha + b\beta)=af(\alpha) + bf(\beta)$ for every $\alpha$ , $\beta$ in U and a , b in F. I guess by showing $F\circ G=id$ and $G\circ F=Id$ Loring has indirectly shown that it is one-one and onto and linear also. Can you refer some article where your definiton of isomorphism is given. Though i know that showing f is one-one and onto is equivalent to showing f is invertible.

Comment: @JasonLiam I learnt linear algebra from Friedberg insel and spence (though I forget which way they phrased the definition of an isomorphism). Anyway these definitions are equivalent because as you say in the end, injective and surjective (i.e bijective) is equivalent to being invertible ... the proof of this being a standard exercise in an introductory proofs course. Hence "your" definition and "mine" are for an isomorphism are equivalent.